# Is there a summary of differences in rendering/behavior between QtWebKit and Chrome/Safari WebKit?

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I wrote a simple Qt application (Windows+Mac) that uses QtWebKit to render
a web site inside a window. 
But I already saw differences in layout and behavior between our app and Chrome
(that uses WebKit as well), e.g.:
- different fonts are displayed for the same web page
- an html anchor link with "javascript:someFunction()" is not working

Is there somewhere a summary list of all such differences (not the entire QtWebKit bug list)?
Also: is there a way to use a WebKit version more similar to Chrome in my application?

Answer (score 4):

WebKit requires the drawing functions to be provided by the platform. Chrome uses a different graphics/drawing library: skia and QtWebKit uses Qt as a the drawing engine.they're

Both skia and qt provide their own widgets which are used in drawing.

Answer (score 2):

Differences may come out of different painting system. About javascript... Just asking, but did you enable JavaScript support in your webkit app? I'm not sure if its enabled by default

Answer (score 2):

Chrome uses it's own JavaScript engine, V8, which was a lot faster for some time. However, WebKit have also implemented a very fast engine called SquirrelFish (and the JIT'ed Extreme variant). Which one is faster is debatable - I recalled WebKit's being faster, but the difference is the order of miliseconds and it depends on a lot of factors - in short, they're both just as fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the site **http://html5test.com/** on your Qt WebView.

```
m_d->m_webView->setUrl(QUrl("http://html5test.com/"));
```

**If you are using the sample HTML project from Qt Quick.*

This page will give you a score for the browser and detailed list of supported features.
You can also compare with other browsers, which is very useful.